# Can I duplicate a web service for testing?

Tags: spring, web-services, jakarta-ee, testing, jboss

I have a REST web service exposed at `http://server:8080/my-production-ws` by JBoss (7). My spring (3.2) configuration has a datasource which points to a `my-production-db` database. So far so good.

I want to test that web service from the client side, including PUT/POST operations but I obviously don't want my tests to affect the production database.

Is there an easy way to have spring auto-magically create another web service entry point at `http://server:8080/my-test-ws` or maybe `http://server:8080/my-production-ws/test` that will have the exact same semantics as the production web service but will use a `my-test-db` database as a data source instead of `my-production-db`?

If this is not possible, what is the standard approach to integration testing in that situation?

I'd rather not duplicate every single method in my controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the spring [Profiles](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) functionality, this should solve the problem. With it its possible to create two datasources with the same bean name in different profiles and then activate only one depending on a parameter passed to the the JVM.